# C-Shell Script Issue

Tags: shell

I have an issue with a c-shell script that I have been coding. I'm storing a datestring in a reference file, to be used for searching (grep) as:

```
Thu Dec  5 05:28:07 2013
```

which is a datetime string. I am reading this string from the file and assigning it to a variable as:

```
set savepointString = `cat savepointFile`
```

When the date is a single digit, there are two spaces between Dec and 5, as `Thu Dec  5 05:28:07 2013`.
When its a double-digit like 10, it becomes `Sat Dec 28 10:57:38 2013`.

The two spaces it reduced to one, when the assignment is done into the variable, and using the string for subsequent grep fails. Can any of you please recommend a fix?

Thanks very much,
Abhilash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try quoting your `cat` command:

```
set savepointString = "`cat savepointFile`"
```

Of you don't, all your whitespace will be collapsed.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks very much, Michael.